# Can someone explain the coeffieient of restitution and how inelastic collision results in momentum but not kinetic energy being conserved?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Can anyone explain how the coefficient of restitution is related to inelastic collisions? How can non-conservation of kinetic energy be true taking the equations of kinematics and conservation of momentum together!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's first start with the following:

1. energy is always conserved
2. momentum is always convserved

Now, the difference between the two is the following.
Let's assume friction etc., some of the kinetic/potential energy will "disappear" as heat. 
On the other hand, momentum is always conserved. No matter whats going on.

So I might be wrong but that coefficient is defined as:

$$\eta = \dfrac{\Delta v_1}{\Delta v_0}$$

it can be shown that this is the same as the quotient of change in kinetic energy:

$$\eta = \sqrt{\dfrac{KE_1}{KE_0}}$$

Because, when we have a collision, we can only "lose" energy (heat, deformation etc) we can conclude:

$$KE_1 \leq KE_2$$

This means that 
$$\eta \leq 1$$

Furthermore $\eta = 1$ is only true if $KE_1 = KE_2$.
This means that we did not lose any energy in the collision and this, by definition, is called "perfectly elastic"

Comment: The critical point here is that your point (1) says "energy" is always conserved, but not  "bulk kinetic energy". There are lots of kinds of energy and no conservation rule for them individually. Ont he other hand there is just the one kind of momentum (at least int eh intro course, one could argue that field momentum is "different" once you get E&M, but that detail doesn't arise in these collisions).